# PHP to JSON Array

Tags: php, json

I need to create a JSON Array like this

```
{
  "channel": {
    "status": "(PHP string)",
  }
}
```

What I have now is

```
$json = array('status' => $_GET['title']);
echo json_encode($json);
```

Which outputs: `{"status":"Hi"}` currently.
Now I need to get it inside "channel" some way but I have no idea how to.

Comment: `$json = array('channel' => array('status' => $_GET['title']));
echo json_encode($json);`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$json = array('channel' => array('status' => isset($_GET['title']) ? $_GET['title'] : ""));
echo json_encode($json);
```

In JSON, braces represent objects (objects contain keys and values). In PHP, associative arrays (using string keys) map to JSON objects, so you must create another array around your existing one, which has the key `channel` and the value is your current array.

Comment: Pretty much the same as @Mark Baker with header and checking if `$_GET['title']`  is set before using it, avoiding some possible error : `PHP Notice:  Undefined index: title in`

Comment: have to trim the first '[',  and the last ']' of json_encode output.

Comment: Yes, you always have to sanitize your output. Some special characters might also break your JSON. I am glad that you make it work.